# Passing a string from .NET to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have tried many ways to pass a string from **.net** to **javascript** including .NET **serializer**, and **register startup scripts**.

I am looking for the simplest way to populate a javascript variable with a string generated in code behind.

This is what I am currently trying but output is `""`

*I am open to other suggestions.*

**VB.NET**

```
Public Property ServerVariable As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim ServerVariable = "'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'"
End Sub
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var data = "<%= ServerVariable %>";
...
List : [data]
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
List : ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Comment: I guess, you already know the answer

Comment: @OP: why have you deleted your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129247/how-to-append-a-variable-name-with-the-current-sqldatarow). I just wanted to post my answer.   You've asked me to show you an example.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I was being savaged by the vultures for not posting a question to their liking. If you could offer me advice on the right direction to take It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Obsidian: some people  have an off-day. Edit your question by providing the result of what you've tried(a compiler error). Then the close-vote(_"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error"_) is pointless. Then undelete it. If you don't want to do that, use a collection type rather than multiple properties. You could do what you want with reflection but that is the very last resort and unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing get and set values. Passed variable `ServerVariable` needs to have a value applied to it.

```
  Private MyVar As String = ""

  Public Property ServerVariable As String
    Get
      Return MyVar
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      MyVar = value
    End Set
  End Property

  MyVar = "['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']"
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment, sorry, btw you can access to public props in the aspx;ascx, so this should help

**vb.net**

```
Public Property ServerVariable As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  ServerVariable = "['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']"

End Sub
```

**JS**

```
var data = "<%= ServerVariable %>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it correctly, only thing is that you need to do `.split(",")` in javascript to get desired result.

Like `var list = console.log(data.split(","));`

Comment: Does this mean I should remove my commas from string in vb?

Comment: No you should keep it as it is, that is the key point here, as you can see that i am splitting that with comma.